# Adding a cache array to recursive knapsack solution?

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm familiar with the naive recursive solution to the [knapsack problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005247/knapsack-problem-recursive-solution-explanation). However, this solution simply spits out the max value that can be stored in the knapsack given its weight constraints. What I'd like to do is add some form of metadata cache (namely which items have/not been selected, using a "one-hot" array `[0,1,1]`).

Here's my attempt:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
    
    def knapSack(self,W, wt, val, n): 
        index = n-1 
        if n == 0 or W == 0 : 
            return 0
        if (wt[index] > W): 
            self.array.append(0)
            choice = self.knapSack(W, wt, val, index) 

        else: 
            option_A = val[index] + self.knapSack( W-wt[index], wt, val, index)
            option_B = self.knapSack(W, wt, val, index)
            if option_A > option_B:
                self.array.append(1)
                choice = option_A
            else:             
                self.array.append(0)
                choice = option_B

        print(int(option_A > option_B)) #tells you which path was traveled
        return choice

  # To test above function 
val = [60, 100, 120] 
wt = [10, 20, 30] 
W = 50
n = len(val) 
# print(knapSack(W, wt, val, n))
s = Solution()
s.knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
>>>
1
1
1
1
1
1

220

s.array
>>>
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

As you can see, `s.array` returns `[1,1,1,1,1,1]` and this tells me a few things. (1), even though there are only three items in the problem set, the knapSack method has been called twice for each item and (2) this is because every item flows through the `else` statement in the method, so `option_A` and `option_B` are each computed for each item (explaining why the array length is 6 not 3.)

I'm confused as to why 1 has been appended in every recursive loop. The item at index 0 would is not selected in the optimal solution. To answer this question, please provide:

(A) Why the current solution is behaving this way
(B) How the code can be restructured such that a one-hot "take or don't take" vector can be captured, representing whether a given item goes in the knapsack or not.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do any printing or did you step through and look at variables? Do suspect something?

Comment: Yes, and I've added the line back in `print(int(option_A > option_B))` which printed 1 every time (6 times)

Comment: While I don't have a solution, The problem with the array is that it is an instance attribute that is shared by all recursion paths and each *item* is taken in at least one of the paths. Why did you choose this design? Why do you want/need a `0/1` array to indicate if something was taken? *Option B* doesn't look like it ever wins. for the recursive calls, why did you decide to pass the complete lists along with an index instead of passing lists with items removed?

Comment: Also `if (wt[index] > W)` is never `True`.

Comment: @wwii Thanks for your attention. The original solution comes from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/?ref=rp I've tried to translate this into an OOP design. However, I might have compromised some functionality in the process. Nonetheless, the code above produces the same output as the code linked.

Comment: Oh and `wt[index] > 1` could return true if a single item is greater than the knapsack capacity. For example `wt, val = [60,20,30], [1000,100,120] ` is a valid possible problem set.

Comment: Why did you make those design decisions I asked about in the previous comment? Did you just copy some code you found and make changes to it without understanding how the original worked? Putting the function in a class doesn't make it OOP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219422/discussion-between-jbuddy-13-and-wwii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (A) Why the current solution is behaving this way

- `self.array` is an instance attribute that is shared by all recursion paths. On one path or another each item is taken and so a one is appended to the list.
- `option_A = val[index]...` takes an item but doesn't append a one to the list.
- `option_B = self.....` skips an item but doesn't append a zero to the list.
- `if option_A > option_B:` When you make this comparison you have lost the information that *made* it - the items that were taken/discarded in the branch;

  - in the suites you just append a one or a zero regardless of how many items *made* those values.
  - The ones and zeroes then represent whether *branch A* (`1`) or *branch B* (`0`) was successful in the current instance of the function.

> (B) How the code can be restructured such that a one-hot "take or don't take" vector can be captured, representing whether a given item goes in the knapsack or not.

It would be nice to know what *you* have taken after running through the analysis, I suspect that is what you are trying to do with `self.array`. You expressed an interest in OOP: instead of keeping track with lists of numbers using indices to select numbers from the lists, make objects to represent the items work with those. Keep the objects in containers and use the functionality of the container to add or remove items/objects from it. Consider how you are going to use a container before choosing one.

- Don't put the function in a class.
- Change the function's signature to accept

  - available weight,
  - a container of items to be considered,
  - a container *holding* the items currently in the sack (*the current sack*).
- Use a collections.namedtuple or a class for the items having value and weight attributes.

  - ```
    Item = collections.namedtuple('Item',['wt','val'])
    ```
- When an item is taken add it to *the current sack*.
- When recursing

  - if going down the *take* path add the return value from the call to *the current sack*
  - remove the item that was **just** considered from the *list of items to be considered* argument.
  - if taken subtract the item's weight from the available weight argument
- When comparing two branches you will need to add up the *values* of each item *the current sack*.

  - return the sack with the highest value
- carefully consider the base case

---

Make the items to be considered like this.

```
import collections
Item = collections.namedtuple('Item',['wt','val'])
items = [Item(wght,value) for wght,value in zip(wt,val)]
```

Add up values like this.

```
value = sum(item.val for item in current_sack)
# or
import operator
val = operator.itemgetter('val')
wt = operator.itemgetter('wt')
value = sum(map(val,current_sack)
```

---

Your solution enhanced with *debugging prints* for the curious.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = []
        self.other_array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    def knapSack(self,W, wt, val, n,j=0):
        index = n-1 
        deep = f'''{' '*j*3}'''
        print(f'{deep}level {j}')
        print(f'{deep}{W} available: considering {wt[index]},{val[index]}, {n})')
        # minor change here but has no affect on the outcome0
        #if n == 0 or W == 0 :
        if n == 0:
            print(f'{deep}Base case found')
            return 0
        print(f'''{deep}{wt[index]} > {W} --> {wt[index] > W}''')
        if (wt[index] > W):
            print(f'{deep}too heavy')
            self.array.append(0)
            self.other_array[index] = 0
            choice = self.knapSack(W, wt, val, index,j+1) 

        else:
            print(f'{deep}Going down the option A hole')
            option_A = val[index] + self.knapSack( W-wt[index], wt, val, index,j+1)
            print(f'{deep}Going down the option B hole')
            option_B = self.knapSack(W, wt, val, index,j+1)
            print(f'{deep}option A:{option_A} option B:{option_B}')
            if option_A > option_B:
                print(f'{deep}option A wins')
                self.array.append(1)
                self.other_array[index] = 1
                choice = option_A
            else:             
                print(f'{deep}option B wins')
                self.array.append(0)
                self.other_array[index] = 0
                choice = option_B

        print(f'{deep}level {j} Returning value={choice}')
        print(f'{deep}---------------------------------------------')
        return choice
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Something that I had a hard time visualizing (and thanks to you pointing out) the solution space is a tree; starting at the root, every time the method is called, a new "split" is introduced with a A & B (or left & right) children. For whatever reason, this idea/realization took a long time to sink in. Thanks for humoring me!

Comment: @jbuddy_13 often it helps to step through code or an algorithm manually with pencil and paper.